# Calculating 2P Elliptic Curve y^2 = x^3 + 3x + 1 mod 7 with P = (0,1)

Tags: elliptic-curves

Elliptic Curve: $y^2 = x^3 + 3x + 1 \bmod 7$

Point : $P(0,1)$

First I calculate lambda for when $P1=P2$

$\lambda = (3x_1^2 +a)/2y_1 = (0 + 3)/2(1) = 3/2$

now calculating $X_3 = \lambda^2 - x_1 - x_2 = (3/2)^2 = 9/4$

Finally Calculating $Y_3 = \lambda(x_1 - x_3) - y_1 = 3/2(0-9/4) - 1 = 19/8$

However, the expected answer is $(4,0)$ I am just wondering where I went wrong thanks in advance.

Comment: $2\cdot 4=1$ modulo $7$, so that $1/2=4$. Then continue.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the help I am curious where did you get the 2 and the 4 and how did you know to multiply them?

Comment: Inverse of $2$ means to find $x$ with $2\cdot x=1$ modulo $7$. Then it is easy to find $x=4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh did you obtain this from the fraction 3/2? Do you just ignore the 3 in the numerator and try to find the inverse of the 2 in the denominator?

Comment: Yes, because $3/2=3\cdot 2^{-1}=3\cdot 4$ modulo $7$. You should know this from your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381479/multiplicative-inverse-of-19-pmod26).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you so much it took me a while but I finally got it to work out. Your little hint helped me so much!